# How the reflected beam of elastically scattered electrons is detected?

Tags: electrons, reflection

*From text*
In the reflection electron microscope (REM) as in the TEM, an electron beam is incident on a surface but instead of using the transmission (TEM) or secondary electrons (SEM), the reflected beam of elastically scattered electrons is detected. 
This technique is typically coupled with reflection high energy electron diffraction (RHEED) and reflection high-energy loss spectroscopy (RHELS). Another variation is spin-polarized low-energy electron microscopy (SPLEEM), which is used for looking at the microstructure of magnetic domains.

How the *reflected beam* of elastically scattered electrons is detected? Tools, techniques ?

Comment: Afaik you would have a better chance on the [engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The reflected beam is detected in the same way that the secondary electrons would be detected - with some current measuring device. The trick is how to detect the reflected beam, not all the secondaries flying around, but you know which way the reflected electrons are going (and their rough energy)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEED pattern and REM image can be obtained simultaneously. By the incidence of electron beam, the electrons scattered at the surface of the sample show RHEED pattern at the back focal plane. REM image (reflected image) can be obtained by choosing the reflecting electrons (for example, a spot of RHEED image) in the RHEED pattern using objective aperture. The electrons using in this method have little momentum for the inside of sample. So the electrons are high sensitive for the sample surface rather than the inner sample.

These patterns and images are displayed to the fluorescent screen. To obtain RHEED patterns and REM image, it takes directly pictures of the fluorescent screen and/or it captures using a CCD camera instead of the fluorescent screen. This function is sometimes equipped at TEM.

Comment: mmm.. but this principle of electron diffraction is used also for generate patterns with [pattern generator](http://www.nanomaker.com/) used for electron beam litography ? Is possible use a reverse REM to project the laser beam of microscope to make patterns on wafer ? If I don't remember bad, but pattern is only a modulated signal between different sources, in this case incident electrons and atom surface diffraction ?

Comment: For the system like pattern generator, the electron beam is scanned on the surfaces. So lenses for scanning are necessary. In the case of REM system with such lenses, there is scanning reflection electron microscope (SREM). By the way, do you want to make patterns on substrates using REM? If my understanding is wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your answer is right, yes I need to to make patterns on substrates using REM. You have some text or pdf reference to understand how make this or how works this process in details ?

Comment: REM is installed in TEM rather than SEM. So the papers can be investigated as the electron beam lithography using TEM. For example, those are [here](http://www.nnin.org/sites/default/files/files/NNINreu06Adams.pdf) and [here](http://www.tem-eels.ca/egerton-laser/preprint/Egerton%26%20Micron'04%20radiation%20damage.pdf). Both are PDF files.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, but in your pdf is not cover only one detail: `modulation system`. I request a question [HERE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12656/what-system-electronic-components-or-physics-mechanism-is-used-to-modulate-signa). Can you help me, please ? Thanks again

Comment: If you want to carry out lithography using TEM equipped with REM. That TEM has to be STEM(scanning transmission electron microscope). At STEM, the scan can be control by own program. But it may be difficult to find the correct position.